# Javascript - AppendChild an input to multiple divs with the same class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an add function to add a new one new input to all the columns with class name domestic.

Now I've created an code in JavaScript, but it only adds it to the first because it's set to the first child. If I remove it I get the an error message (" appendChild is not a function ")

Is it possible to do this? I've searched on numerous post's  and haven't found any answer.

HTML

```
 <!-- START ONJECTIVES CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container" id="weighings">
      <!-- DOMESTIC NAME -->
      <div class="colum" id="columtext">
        <p>Domestic</p>
      </div>
       <!-- COLUM 4 DESCRIPTION -->
      <div class="colum discription domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Description</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 5 LOW -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Low</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 6 MEDIUM -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Medium</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 7 HIGH -->
      <div class="colum domestic last" id="regio">
        <p>High</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 8 LOW -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Low</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 9 MEDIUM -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>Medium</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
      <!-- COLUM 10 HIGH -->
      <div class="colum domestic" id="regio">
        <p>High</p>
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
        <input id="box" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
      </div>
     </div>
      <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

SCSS

```
           #box{
             margin-top:5px;
             width:10px;
             height:10px;
             background:black;
            }

        .colum{
            display: block;
            width: 200px;
          text-align:center;
        }

    #regio{
      width:50px;
      margin-right:10px;
      input{
        width:50px;
      }
    }

  .row{
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
  }
```

Javascript

```
    document.getElementById("newrow").onclick = function () {
    var ok = true;

     if (ok === true) {
       for(i=0;i<8;i++){
          var input = document.createElement('input');
          input.id = 'box';
          input.type = 'text';
          input.oninput = 'calculate()';

       document.getElementsByClassName('domestic')[0].appendChild(input);
       }
    }
};
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/pNELXM?editors=0110

Comment: jQuery  .each()  why re-invent the wheel...

Comment: jquery is massively overkill to pull for a .each, and maybe he's learning. This can be done in three lines of code in JS.
    for(i=0;i< elements.length; ;i++) {
    elements[i].appendChild(input);
  }

Comment: @diabetesjones

Yes i'm still learning, but the line of code doesn't work T.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only putting it on the first row with this line of code:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('domestic')[0].appendChild(input);
```

You can see that it is getting the [0] (the first element in the array of elements with a class of domestic), then never going to later one. We need to iterate over the array of elements with the class name domestic, so let's save it to a variable, and do just that.

I'd do it like this:

```
  document.getElementById("newrow").onclick = function () {

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('domestic');
  // if there are no elements found with the class of domestic, do nothing.
if(elements.length == 0) return false;

  // otherwise, lets do it! We can make the input box ONCE and append it to multiple divs, because it is always the same box we are appending. Much faster. That is why it is out of the loop now.
  var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = 'box';
    input.type = 'text';
    input.oninput = 'calculate()';

  //we set the condition to the LENGTH OF OUR ARRAY which contains the elements of the class name document.
  for(i=0;i< elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].appendChild(input);
  }
};
```

jQuery:

```
$('#newrow').on('click', function() {
   var eles = $('.domestic');
   eles.each(function($k, $v) {
      $(this).append(input);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried applying it, but it just adds it to the last one now

Comment: I had a typo in the for loop, it was just pseudo-code to get you started.

I had an extra semicolon after "elements.length" - try now?

If you want to use jQuery, it would be easy as well. Let me edit that in.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the collection, add the input:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('domestic');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].appendChild(input);
}
```